# Advice to understand simple part of my code #1 (MVC / PHP OOP / Register)

Tags: php

Greeting people,

**Intro**:
I am learning / practicing PHP.
So, I started with simple project and will make more complex stuff.
I know basics in OOP, but for some reason sometimes I get stuck (I guess lacking experience).
I searched and try to understand but didn't find answer, so I thought maybe here I can post.
I also don't know the way that I am making things is Correct Way (Coding Standards and Best Practices). So, if something is wrong don't hesitate to correct me.

**Info**:
I made Register Function and it works, but I don't fully understand Why / How ?
I use PHP OOP / PDO / MVC (not as framework).

My **Model** is **Register.class.php** / my **Controller** is **RegisterController.class.php**.
My RegisterController class has 3 private Properties (**$pseudoProperty**, **$emailProperty**, **$passwordProperty**). 
Theses **3 private Properties** I use inside my Model like:
 protected function preparationToCreateNewUserInDB($pseudoProperty, $emailProperty, $passwordProperty).

**Question**:
So, this is what I see:

- without any getters and setters
- without any Extends (My Register class doesn't extends RegisterController)
- I use private Properties (I get access) 
  Why / How I can use like that my **3 private Properties** ? Is it because I have **public __construct()** ?

[image of some codes to help](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-zn3b_h1niZhVrCSTFqchGct_tAG1_DU/view?usp=sharing)

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: Please, do not use Images to post your code/errors. Copy & Paste your code/errors directly in your question. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: ok, for images (didn't knew)

Answer (score -1):

yes, you have already set them via the `__contruct` method,
and about the best practices of styling code at PHP,I encourage you to read the following article about [PHP Coding Guidelines & Best Practices](https://flowframework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/CodingGuideLines/PHP.html)